# How do I show a button depending on which field is selected?PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have [this site](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/).

At the bottom you will find some products ... four of them have the word "buton1" or "buton2"

The site is made with [this Wordpress plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/) and custom fields.

Basically I have two radio buttons.

I want to put my button, depending on which item is selected, in the admin panel.

To do this, I tried the following code:

**CODE PHP:**

```
<p class="test">   <?php

$variable = get_field('button');
echo $variable;
if(buton1 is selected)
{
 <a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a> //display the button
}else if(buton2 is selected){
 //hide the button 
}
?>
```

You can help me please tell me what I should do to fill my code?

How can I verify that the button is selected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post the code for `get_field()`

Comment: `get_field()` is a method that can Retrieving a field as a variable.You can find in the documentation in first line

Comment: ok, then post the HTML code for your radio buttons...

Comment: No need for this, radio buttons are added automatically by the plugin ... and are found only in the admin panel

Comment: I just need to check which of the buttons is selected

Comment: ok, well 2 of the three links you posted didn't work so I removed them. based on the docs you can probably just do `if(get_field("button")){...}`

Answer (score 1):

when a form is submitted, all the elements in the form are posted to the submitted page with name and values, in `get` or `post` scope. depending on the form type.

You can get the selected button as follows in php:

```
$button_value = get_field('button_name');
echo $button_value;

if($button_value == 1)
{
     <a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a> //display the button
}
else if($button_value == 2){
     //hide the button 
}
```

Comment: your example works but please tell me why the code appears so ... give him a refresh to the site and see how it appears

Comment: <?php
$button_value = get_field('button_name');
echo $button_value;
if($button_value == 1)
{
     <a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a> 
}
?>

Comment: @gigi i don't understand what u mean? is there any problem u still facing?